# Rails webpacker:install fails with generic error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ubuntu-22.04

I am new to Ruby on Rails and this is the very first project I have attempted. I installed Rails and got to the screen that lets me know that I have successfully installed Rails. [Rails Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kiwif.png)

I ran `rails g controller home index` to create my first web page. It completed successfully and displayed this:

```
user@Ubuntu:~/dev/app$ rails g controller home index
Running via Spring preloader in process 183578
      create  app/controllers/home_controller.rb
       route  get 'home/index'
      invoke  erb
      create    app/views/home
      create    app/views/home/index.html.erb
      invoke  test_unit
      create    test/controllers/home_controller_test.rb
      invoke  helper
      create    app/helpers/home_helper.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      invoke  assets
      invoke    scss
      create      app/assets/stylesheets/home.scss
```

I tried to access the page, but it gave me this error:

```
Webpacker can't find application.js in /home/user/dev/app/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
}
```

I tried changing `cache_manifest: false` and `extract_css: false` in webpacker.yml to `true` but it didn't seem to help. I felt that webpacker was not installed correctly so I ran `rails webpacker:install`. It fails and never successfully completes:

```
`user@Ubuntu:~/dev/app$ bundle exec rails webpacker:install
    conflict  config/webpacker.yml
Overwrite /home/user/dev/app/config/webpacker.yml? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdhm] n
        skip  config/webpacker.yml
Copying webpack core config
       exist  config/webpack
   identical  config/webpack/development.js
   identical  config/webpack/environment.js
   identical  config/webpack/production.js
   identical  config/webpack/test.js
Copying postcss.config.js to app root directory
   identical  postcss.config.js
Copying babel.config.js to app root directory
   identical  babel.config.js
Copying .browserslistrc to app root directory
   identical  .browserslistrc
rails aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `exists?' for Dir:Class
/home/user/dev/app/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/dev/app/bin/spring:10:in `require'
/home/user/dev/app/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/user/dev/app/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => app:template`
```

Any idea how to resolve this? This error is so generic, I am having trouble searching for answers.

**rails aborted!** 
**NoMethodError: undefined method `exists?' for Dir:Class**

Environment:
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop |
Rails version: 6.1.7 |
Ruby version: 3.2.0

Comment: I used to deal with errors like this all the time but off hand I forget the possible solutions If you start over with rails 7 you can avoid webpacker altogether I suggest watch gorails video for rails 7 with js bundling and bootstrap You would create a new app with a command similar to ```rails _7.0.4.1_ new some_app_name --js esbuild --css bootstrap and then you'll have scripts in your package.json which will be caused to run when you start the development server with bin/dev which is in turn a script also which calls procfile.dev and then in turn foreman which runs ```rails s```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded my version of Rails to 7 and version of Ruby to 3.0.5 and was able to bypass the webpacker issue. The problem seemed to be incompatibility between the versions of Rails and Ruby I was using. [**This**](https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/rails/versions/compatibility-table.html) is a table of the recommended Ruby version for each version of Rails.

[image: Recommended Ruby version for Rails version]

https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/rails/versions/compatibility-table.html